# How to limit framerate in a curses program?

Tags: c, curses, frame-rate

I've been trying to make a game using ncurses.
However, I am stumped with how to make the timing part of my main loop work.
Would someone be able to add some insight into how I could add framerate code to my main loop, while keeping portability and not compromising speed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to handle this type of problem I believe is to pass in the duration since the last loop (often called delta) as a parameter to the system. This allows you to update the progress of entities in the game based on the amount of real world time that has passed. For example:

```
new_position = old_position + delta*speed
```

This allows entities in your game to move at a constant speed independent of the frame rate of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have functionality to update your gamestate after a small period of time, next you need to be able to poll the user for input. If you do not specify otherwise, ncurses will block when you ask for input. To prevent this, look up the init functions [here](http://linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/init.html#ABOUTINIT). In particular, the halfdelay() function may be of use of you (it implements a sort of framerate).

Just remember to check for ERR on the return value of getch() when using this mode.